# How can I get a printable version of a node?

Tags: theming, nodes, 10

I have a node with a simple article in it (an `<H1>`, a bit of <`H2`>s and some `<p>`s).

If I print this page from the web browser as-is, I will get it with grandiose spacings, Drupal blocks, images and even JavaScript popups repeating in each printable page often.

Copy-pasting the node content into LibreOffice Writer where I can easily remove the images and don't get the Drupal blocks and the JavaScript popups was not rendered properly with some whitespaces actually turning into strange gray rectangles (are these line breaks?).
I don't use Microsoft Word so I don't have a say on this one.

Anyway, how will you suggest to get a printable version of a Drupal node?

Comment: Not really Drupal specific, but the IMHO best solution: Create CSS styles in your theme specifically targeting `@media print { /* rules for printing here */ }`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#print)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Printer and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/printable) module.